# Linux - even using exit command, it pass result to pipe

Tags: linux, awk, pipe, exit

I am writing a script, which find the max length of line in all files and directories(with FIND), I get names of files as script arguments.
I have while loop which goes through all files and print longest line from each. After this while loop goes through all arguments, there is a PIPE that passes these results to awk which should just pick the longest one and print it.
**This is code:**

```sh
{ while [ ! $# -eq 0 ]; do
    if [ -f "$1" ]; then    
        awk -v name="$1:" ' {
            if ( length > ln ) 
            { ln=length ;content[i=1]=$0 ;line[i]=NR } 
            else if ( length == ln )
            { content[++i]=$0 ; line[i]=NR }
        }
        END{ for(j=1;j<=i;j++) print name, line[j], ln, content[j] }' "$1"
    
    elif [ -d "$1" ]; then
        mapfile -d '' files_arr < <(find "$1" -type f \( -name "*[[:space:]]*" -o -name "*" \) -perm -a=r -print0)  
        for i in "${files_arr[@]}"; do
            awk -v name="$i:" ' {
            if ( length > ln ) 
                { ln=length ;content[i=1]=$0 ;line[i]=NR } 
            else if ( length == ln )
                { content[++i]=$0 ; line[i]=NR }
            }
            END{ for(j=1;j<=i;j++) print name, line[j], ln, content[j] }' "$i"
        done
    else
        echo "Error: '$1': File like this doesnt exist." > /dev/stderr
        exit 2
    fi
    shift
    done
} | awk ' { if ( $3>max ) { max=$3 ; result[i=1]=$0 } else if ( $3==max ) { result[++i]=$0 } } 
END{ for(j=1;j<=i;j++) print result[j] } '
```

The problem is, when I have file, which doesnt exist as 2. argument, then I would like to print error message and exit, but my script print error and also print results from previous script argument (f.e. first argument).

Thank you once again for your help!

Comment: Please create and post a [mcve] (emphasis on **minimal**) that just demonstrates your problem, don't post whatever code you have lying around that **includes** somewhere within it code that has the problem as that makes it much harder for us to identify the issue and help you. See [ask]. Also, make sure to include the shebang that'll show us which shell you use.

Comment: Please include the error you are getting, and the input that causes it.

Answer (score 1):

Piping the output directly to `awk` will run the `while` loop and `awk` in parallel. So as soon as the loop `echo`s a matching line for the first file `awk` can process that line and output the result. It does not wait for all files to be checked first.

If you want to output *only* an error message and exit if the second file does not exist you should check this first:

```sh
if ! [ -f "$2" ]; then
  echo "'$2' is not a file" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

If you need to check this for every argument you can expand [`$@`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters-1):

```sh
for file in "$@"; do
  if ! [ -f "$file" ]; then
    echo "'$file' is not a file" >&2
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

Otherwise you could try to catch/buffer the output of your `while` loop into a variable or temporary file and only pipe it to `awk` after all files were processed successfully.

Comment: thank you sir, this really helped